# ConcurrentSkipListSet, add method is failing in Java 8

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

Pending **ConcurrentSkipListSet** getting fixed (http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8060435), my brain is failing trying to come up with a work around.

Anyone else having problems with it in Java 8? The add method worked fine in Java 7 but is breaking with Java 8 and causing major havok with the event-system of my audio engine.

I'm thinking of trying to program an alternative. It is important that there be an absolute minimum of blocking occurring. (Am trying to avoid using synchronization.)

The adds are "AudioEvents" (a class I created) ordered by frame number (a long). Adds occur on one thread, and references to the collection occur on the audio thread.

Stuff like this isn't supposed to break between versions.

Comment: Some folks at Concurrency-interest are taking a look. It appears this is different from the bug report I located and mentioned above. I'll post a solution when we get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question, rather than deleting the question, as the information might prove useful for others if a problem with ConcurrentSkipListSet comes up.

My error proved to be a poorly written implementation of Comparable. There are requirements listed in the JavaDoc that are supposed to be enforced which I was careless about.

When the implementation of ConcurrentSkipListSet was revised in Java 8, the hole in my compare resulted in an infinite spin.

The variable *frame* is a long.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(AudioEvent other)
{
    if (frame < other.getFrame()) return -1;
    // correct
    if (frame > other.getFrame()) return 1;
    // following is the compare error that WAS here
    // if (frame >= other.getFrame()) return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

So, a reminder. It is easy to mistakenly jump to conclusions about system code that is relatively mystifying (and ConcurrentSkipListSet qualifies, for me, on that score!). One should first strongly check the code that one wrote that interacts with these "mysterious things."

[Icon for being embarrassed here.]

Comment: That’s the time were *unit testing* should be advertised. Especially for interfaces having a contract that applies to all implementations, like with `Comparable`, it is easy to write test code checking all these invariants. If there was such a test code telling you that your code fails (without `ConcurrentSkipListSet` being involved) you saved a lot of time, probably much more than writing that test case takes…

Comment: Agreed. Prime candidate for a unit test, especially since the requirements are so clearly posted in the JavaDoc--it would be easy to make corresponding tests.

Comment: Hey, thanks Phil. This has saved me.  I've spend almost a full day tracing an inconsistent Windows-specific application freeze, but at least now its resolved.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use the source of ConcurrentSkipListSet in OpenJDK 7, which, if you don't have or are too lazy to download, is available on GrepCode or DocJar.

Comment: To provide you with a followup: My first attepts were to make use of the entire source of either Java7's or Java8's OpenJDK ConcurrentSkipListSet, but they have failed. It is certainly interesting to see the source, but it is too deeply enmeshed with other code, and mysterious (to me) UNSAFE-related errors that get thrown. I haven't tried to tackle a rewrite yet, and suspect that the coding will be over my head. But it is good to have this available as a reference. I will study it some more and see if it is something I can figure out.

Comment: Ah - yes, Unsafe. I've worked with it in the past, you cannot use the singleton because its so volatile it is secured by a class loader check. Here's an excellent post on the topic: http://mishadoff.com/blog/java-magic-part-4-sun-dot-misc-dot-unsafe/

Comment: Great article! Meanwhile, I uncovered my error and this particular "crisis" has been resolved. Thanks!